# when should an action be added to init and when should it be added to wp_head

Tags: init, wp-head

How do you know when to add your action to init or wp_head. In particular with regards to scripts and styles, but also any other action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Codex [Action Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference):

> `init` Runs after WordPress has finished loading but before any
>   headers are sent. Useful for
>   intercepting $_GET or $_POST triggers.
>
> `wp_head` Runs when the template calls the wp_head function. This hook
>   is generally placed near the top of a
>   page template between <head> and
>   </head>. This hook does not take any
>   parameters.

Basically `wp_head` runs when page is already being loaded, while `init` runs before that.

Also don't forget that `init` fires on admin pages as well and anything front-end related must be excluded from there with `!is_admin()` check.